# is there another way to do use stringstream?

Tags: c++

I am currently using `stringstream` to pass a string over but I was wondering if there is another way of doing it? below is a snip shot of how it's done. as I am still quite new to c++, I am not sure if this is the best way to do it or there could be an alternative as I heard using string stream slows down the process and was hoping to learn more.

```
string Circle::toString()
{
   stringstream sentence;
   sentence << "Shape [" << index <<"]" << endl;
   sentence << "Name: " << name << endl;

   if (containsWarpSpace == false)
       sentence << "Special Type: NS" << endl;
   else
       sentence << "Special Type: WS" << endl;

   sentence << "Area: " << area << " units square" << endl;
   sentence << "Vertices: " << endl;
   sentence << "Point[0]: (" << center[0] << ", " << center[1] << ")" << endl;
   sentence << endl;
   sentence << "Points on perimeter: " << endl;
   bool trueFalse= false;
   int count = 0;
   for ( int y = center[1] - unit; y < center[1] + unit + 1; y++)
   {
      for ( int x = center[0] - unit; x < center[0] + unit + 1; x++)
      {
         trueFalse = isPointOnShape (x, y);
         if (trueFalse == true)
         {
            if (count %6 == 0)
                sentence << "(" << x << ", " << y << ")";
            else
                sentence << ", (" << x << ", " << y << ")";

            count++;
            if (count %6 == 0)
                sentence << endl;
         }
      }
   }

   if (count == 0)
       sentence << "none!";

   sentence << endl;
   count = 0;
   sentence << "Points within shape: " << endl;
   for (int y = center[1] - unit; y < center[1] + unit + 1; y++)
   {
      for ( int x = center[0] - unit; x < center[0] + unit + 1; x++)
      {
         trueFalse = isPointInShape (x, y);

         if (trueFalse == true)
         {
            if (count %6 == 0)
                sentence << "(" << x << ", " << y << ")";
            else
                sentence << ", (" << x << ", " << y << ")";

            count++;
            if (count %6 == 0)
                sentence << endl;
         }
      }
   }
   if (count == 0)
       sentence << "none!";

   sentence << endl;    
   return sentence.str();
}
```

hope some one could guide me on this

Comment: Please try providing a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by providing a full example including the main method and also reducing the code to only the pieces, that are relevant for your question.

Comment: Get it working first, then worry about performance. As a first improvement, make a new type for points and overload `operator <<` for it so you can do `sentence << Point(x, y)`

Comment: I would not worry about performance if it is fast enough. If you think it is too slow, there are many ways to do for faster execution, but it might be less elegant. I would beautify your code first a bit. ```trueFalse``` is not a good name for a boolean variable.

Comment: That is an appropriate use of `stringstream`. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the information

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using `stringstream` is fine, but you need to consider that your code creates a `stringstream` object in every `toString()` call, which, in turn, leads to memory allocation. For example, if you have a thousand circles to dump into a string, then there will be a thousand memory allocations for the underlying memory buffer of a temporary `stringstream` object, eventually following by a thousand deallocations (and maybe reallocations if the initial buffer isn't big enough).

Most likely, you will be using `toString()` for debugging or logging, where performance doesn't matter that much. However, there is room for improvement. Think about what you're going to do with the string returned by `Circle::toString()`? Most likely, the string is going to be displayed, written to a file, or maybe streamed via a network. You'll be doing something like `cout << circle.toString()`. Instead of creating a temporary `stringstream` object, converting it into a temporary string, and finally writing it into a stream, you can write it into the output stream directly.

```cpp
void Circle::toStream(ostream &os)
{
    os << "Shape [" << index <<"]\n";
    // ...
    os << endl;
}
```

In the header file declare `operator<<`. That allows you writing `cout << circle;`

```cpp
class Circle {
    // ...
public:
    void toStream(ostream &os);

    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &os, const Circle &c) {
        c.toStream(os);
        return os;
    }
};
```

If Circle has a base class, then it is a good idea to declare `toStream` as virtual on the base level:

```cpp
class Object {
public:
    virtual ~Object() = default;

    virtual void toStream(ostream &os) = 0;

    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &os, const Object &obj) {
        obj.toStream(os);
        return os;
    }    
};

class Circle : public Object {
public:
    void toStream(ostream &os) override;
};

class Rectangle : public Object {
public:
    void toStream(ostream &os) override;
};
```

Now you can print any object to any output stream without performance drawback while still keeping your code clean.

```cpp
Circle circle1, circle2;
Rectangle rectangle;
// ...
// print circle to stdout
cout << "My circles:\n" << circle1 << circle2;
cout << "My rectangle:\n" << rectangle;
// write circles to a file
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("circle.log");
myfile << circle1 << circle2;
myfile.close();
```

Finally, if you need a string after all, then you can create a helper method:

```cpp
string Circle::toString()
{
    stringstream sentence;
    toStream(sentence);
    return sentence.str();
}
```